# Why is setCenter implementation inconsistent on mobile v. laptop?

Tags: mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have some very straightforward code that works fine on my laptop running Chrome, but not on my Android (Gingerbread 2.3.6) browser:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
//define Map ("map") and LatLng ("myLoc")
function handleResize() {
    if( map != null ) {
        map.setCenter(myLoc);
        //test to see if device knows it has been resized
        var w1 = $(mapDiv).width();
        alert(w1 + " " + myLoc);
    }
}
```

As you can see, all I'm doing is trying to recenter after a resize event.  Any idea why this doesn't work on my phone?  (And, yes, the phone knows it's been resized.)

Comment: What's the actual problem? Does it throw an error? Does the map not get re-centered?

Comment: Does the API know it's been resized? What happens if you add in triggering the map `resize` event? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map (Scroll down to Events)

Comment: Update: Now I realize the map is successfully recentered in both cases, but on the Android the map then moves by an offset defined in pixels (it's insensitive to zoom level).  So, fault is with browser, not Google Maps. _Never mind!_